# Blocking google.com and maps.googleapis.com breaks the site

Tags: bug, profile-page

I would like to change my profile, but for some reason the profile page breaks cause I blocked scripts from maps.googleapis.com. Whatever map feature that is, it cannot be so essential to the site that the page should not need to bother with graceful degradation, can it?

Also I know the google recaptcha is a really handy thing, but aside from allowing google to track stackexchange users, recaptcha is also hardly the most secure captcha.

Even the ajax.googleapis.com could be backed by secondary cdns easily.

My point is, it shouldn't be hard to modify the site to allow its use to users who block google scripts. Maybe I am just 'one of those', but in my experience a suprising amount of people seek to avoid google tracking. So wouldn't it be worth the (little) effort?

Comment: There's basically no point asking this here - technical changes to the entire network belong on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) .

Comment: @Miniman Is it possible (for a mod) to move the question there? Or is it no problem if I re-ask it there?

Comment: Yeah, we can't help you here on RPG.Meta -- the chances of SE staff seeing this are rather...minimal :/

Comment: @user7863867 It's no problem if you re-ask there.

Comment: thanks a bunch: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295252/blocking-google-com-and-maps-googleapis-com-breaks-the-site
I guess this question here could be closed then?

Comment: @Miniman Bug reports can be posted on child metas like this one *or* meta stack exchange, there's no difference. [Staff confirmation here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240568/152515) Their internal tools track all metas.

Comment: @Shalvenay see this message ↑

Comment: @doppelgreener -- ah, thanks, understood